# How to use _root and this[] in same line?

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs5

Here's a chunk of code that WORKS when it's on the main timeline:

```
var DysonTarget:String = "S"+(random(40)+1);
this[DysonTarget].MyType = "Dyson Sphere";
this[DysonTarget].gotoAndStop(this[DysonTarget].MyType);
```

It's choosing a number between 1 and 40, adding an S before it, and going into one of forty movie clips on the main stage with instance name S1, S2. . . S40 etc.  Then it will display an image in the chosen clip.  But to make this truly work the way I want to, I have to put the above code inside a movie clip.  So I tried this, after declaring my variable on the main stage:

```
_root.this[DysonTarget].MyType = "Dyson Sphere";
_root.this[DysonTarget].gotoAndStop(this[DysonTarget].MyType);
```

It didn't compile, the error message said "Expected a field name after the '.' operator.  Trying it with _parent returned the same message.  With _level0 didn't work at all, and placing the _root and _parent inside the bracket didn't work either.  I haven't been able to find any answer online because trying to type "this" into a search is too vague to return an answer about the actual command.

. . .help me :(

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine who is a software developer helped me on this one.  Here's what we figured out:

First you declare variable DysonTarget on the main timeline:

```
var DysonTarget:String = "S" + (random(40)+1);
```

Then inside the movie clip, use this:

```
_level0[DysonTarget].MyType = "Dyson Sphere';
_level0[_level0.DysonTarget].gotoAndStop(_level0[_level0.DysonTarget].MyType);
```

I've tried this a few other ways, and the above method is the only one that works the way it's supposed to.  But it works!  My impression is the brackets tell it to look for an object named what the variable is set to, rather than an object with the same name as the variable.